# Which bitrate is needed for dvd quality?

Tags: bitrate

As far as I know, cd quality for mp3s is at least 128 kbps.
What should the video bitrate be to obtain dvd quality?

Note I'm using mp4 container with mp3 audio and mpeg4 video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it depends on the used codec as well, it is not all about bitrate. But it is possible to have a reasonable quality @3,5 Mbit/s. But using the maximum range of ~9Mbit/s. usually looks much better, but the space of a DVD is limited, so that it is not enough for a 90 minute movie. The best thing is to try different settings for your mpeg4. Remember that this video must obey DVD restriction in order to be played in a DVD player.

Comment: I'm using the mpeg4 codec, but I usually have a bitrate around 500 kbps. So is the minimum bitrate 3mbps? I'm using a 720x576 resolution

Comment: And I'm going to use on my pc

Comment: The minimum is determined by the codec, that will accept a specific minimum value only. The 3,5Mbit is the value, that DVD used to have in the period before MPEG4 and BluRay were on. Since the MPEG4 is much more efficient, it will offer better quality @3,5Mbit as MPEG2, but to set an univeral value that fit all your requiries is hardly possible. Compare the bitrates of the video streaming companies ( I won't tell names ). They use different rates depending in the internet connection speed. They get moderate quality @1,5-2Mbit and even more with ~3-5Mbit. Once again: Why not give it some tries?

Comment: Yep, I'm going to

Comment: why mp3 audio? That's not standard for mp4, why not use the default audio codec, which is way more efficient as well as more compatible.

Comment: Well, looks like 1.5 maps work for me.